# How to Link Lightning Design System CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, salesforce-lightning

I'm finishing coding a booking website with HTML/CSS but there's probably a problem with the link tag in the `<head>`.

Since I have no design skills, I decided to use [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) for styling the website. But when I launch my site, the CSS does not appear.
Here is the `<head>` tag of the site's home page where I insert the style sheet link:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <!-- Set the viewport width to device width for mobile -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Accueil</title>
    <!-- Link to lightningdesignsystem for page style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/_next/static/css/1b7615e9db05d7a5f4b8.css" />
    <!-- Jquery calendar used for bookings -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
    <script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Please guide me on how to properly link the styles.

Comment: Well, that link to the stylesheet appears to be dead to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they don't have any officially supported CDN. But you can try this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/design-system/2.5.0/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css

Read More: https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/issues/169

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is solved.